# Specify custom reference key name in Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I attempted to create a custom primary key `product_code` for my `products` table instead of allowing Rails to default the table to using `id`. The `products` table has a `has_one` relationship with the `metrics` table, although when I generate a migration using `belongs_to` specifying `:product` - the foreign key in my database is `product_id` rather than `product_code`. How can I generate the migration and force the `foreign_key` in the `metrics` table to be `product_code` rather than `product_id`?

I have the following migrations and model relationship.

```
# Product migration
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products, id: false do |t|
      t.string :product_code, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :products, :product_code, unique: true
  end
end

# models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key :product_code
  has_one :metric
end

# Metric migration
class CreateMetrics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :metrics do |t|
      t.belongs_to :product
      t.string :department
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

# models/metric.rb
class Metric < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
class CreateMetrics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :metrics do |t|
      t.string :department
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :metrics, : products, column: : product_code, primary_key: "product_code"
  end
end
```

In your `Product` and `Metric` models, you should also specify `foreign_key`:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key :product_code
  has_one :metric, foreign_key: 'product_code'
end

class Metric < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product, foreign_key: 'product_code'
end
```